# WebStorm TypeScript type visualisation not showing initial type on type hover

Tags: typescript, ide, webstorm

In WebStorm, when I use more complex typings the IDE does not show the resulting type (on hover over `TransformedFruit`) but just the formula used to transform another type into what we want. Initial type shows `{}` instead:

[image: WebStorm example]

In Visual Studio Code for example, when doing the same thing it shows the resulting type correctly:

[image]

I feel like I am missing something, some setting or whatever that is not set properly? How can I make `Initial type` show up correctly in WebStorm?

Snippet:

```js
type Fruit =
    | {
    name: "apple";
    color: "red";
}
    | {
    name: "banana";
    color: "yellow";
}
    | {
    name: "orange";
    color: "orange";
};

type TransformedFruit = {
    [F in Fruit as F['name']]: F['name']
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with ctrl + mouse over the TransformedFruit

Comment: Is there a way to default to this view ?